# Facebook App Review - How to allow FB reviewer to test manage_pages permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have an app that allows users of a (basically)WordPress site to share their posts to their Facebook business page (not user feed). Everything works great, I just have to submit the app to FB for review because I need the manage_pages and publish_pages permissions. How do I allow the Facebook reviewer to test this functionality when they need to have permissions attached to a FB page to be able to share a post to it?

I have created a login on my site for the reviewer. I have also created a test user on the app that the FB reviewer will be able to use, and I have used that test user to created a test page but the page is not accessible by my app or by any other user. The test page is set to Public. As I understand from what I've read in the FB docs, content by a test user (I'm assuming an FB business page qualifies as "content") is only visible to other test users. How can I set this up for FB to be able to review this?

Comment: They have accounts available to test that have access to their own pages they manage ...

Comment: ok, I didn't assume that. Seemed to me like they wanted everything set up for them. I'll submit for review and check back to confirm if it was all fine. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, no problems and the app was approved. This was a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by CBroe, Facebook testers have their own pages with which to test permissions like this. I was over-worrying.